# XLAM / XLA Addins: is there a better way?

Tags: vba, excel

This post is about installing XLAM's without creating links. (Everyone hates links).  Consider the trivial addin:

```
    Public Function UDF_HELLO(x)
        UDF_HELLO = "Hello " & x
    End Function
```

Put this code and nothing else into a Module and save as "Hello.xlam" on the Desktop (and NOT in the default excel addins folder).  Next, while HELLO.XLAM is still open, create a new XLSX workbook with the formula

```
      =UDF_Hello("world")
```

in cell A1, which simply displays "Hello world" in that cell.  Save the workbook and exit Excel.  Now, if you reopen the workbook without the XLAM, Excel will complain about "links to other sources ...".  Whether you click "Update" or "Don't Update", Excel will mangle the formula in cell A1 like this:

```
    ='C:\Documents and Settings\tpascale\Desktop\Hello.xlam'!UDF_Hello("world")
```

Very often this "forced-linkage" is NOT desirable. In my computing environment there is a lot of ad-hoc analysis and it makes no sense to impose an install regimen on every XLAM we throw together to solve the problem of the day.  I just want to hand out XLAM files to users and let those users open them when they need them, WITHOUT having to worry about the slightest mis-step causing their formulas to get mangled.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to instruct Excel to NEVER construct external links for UDFs, and simply to use UDFs if they're loaded and return #VALUEs otherwise ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way around this with .xla/.xlam add-ins.

But this issue does not occur with .xll add-ins.
These can be created in C using the [Excel 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9129a28e-d11c-4ac3-aee3-cbb5496908cf), or in managed languages like VB.NET or C# using the free [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) library.

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Excel-DNA. This issue is one of the reasons I went with the .xll interface for making managed UDF add-ins.)

Comment: I know how to make COM visible functions in VB.Net or C#. These can be called from VBA but not from the formula bar. What is the absolute simplest way to get them callable from the formula bar ? Is it your Excel-DNA or something else ? Visual Studio does a nice job of generating all the COM-interop stuff - but as far as I know doesn't generate anything for you w.r.t. excel addins.

Comment: Supposedly, the simplest (and only MS-supported) way to make .NET functions available as UDFs to Excel is to create an Automation Add-in: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/excelnetauto.aspx. But automation add-ins are slow, need to be registered on the machine, and have limited support for adding function descriptions, categories etc. Excel-DNA solves all of those problems, leaving you with a single .xll requiring no installation that users can just click on to open. If you already have Visual Studio installed and know what an attribute is, you'll find Excel-DNA easy to use and just works.

Comment: Ok many thanks - I'll be trying Excel DNA.  I took a quick look at your "Excel DNA Hello World Function" - very nice.  Ideally I'd just wrap the VBA code in your DNA XML, no IDE - very simple  -  except that my UDFs rely on VBA classes.  Can those also be wrapped in this very lightweight manner ?  If yes, great, if no, I'll probably bite the bullet & convert to .NET with DNA.

Comment: Your VBA classes would have to be ported to VB.NET. They can be compiled at runtime from .dna files or pre-compiled into .dlls and referenced from the .dna files with your functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have them open the .xla file and have an Auto_Open procedure install the add-in.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=693

After excel closes you can have the add-in uninstall itself.

```
oAddIn.Installed = False
```

You can give your add-in a setting for the user to not uninstall after every use by using a worksheet named something then have cell A1 equal to true or false.

I haven't tested this but hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work to resolve your issue though it does not instruct Excel regarding external links. I have tested it myself by creating the XLAM, saving it to my desktop, installing it in the Excel add-ins and then using it on a new workbook.

Steps:

1. Once you have saved the add-in, close it.
2. Go to Excel Options-->Add-Ins
3. In the Manage drop-down select Excel Add-ins and press 'Go'
4. In the 'Add-Ins'dialogue that appears click 'Browse' and navigate to
   the add-in you just created.   Select it and hit 'Ok'
5. If prompted to save the add-in in the add-ins folder, select 'No'.
   Selecting 'Yes' may cause an error if the add-in file suffix does
   not match the version of Excel being used.
6. Your add-in should appear in the 'Add-Ins available' scrollbox,
   check its box and hit 'Ok'
7. Your add-in should now be active whenever you open Excel.
8. Test this by opening a new workbook and try using your UDF.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this problem by:

1. Saving an XLA/XLAM file (outside Personal folder, of course)
2. Connect to it in Tools - Addins
3. Write pseudo macros in your current Excel file that links to those macros / functions in the XLA/XLAM file.

See the detailed instructions in my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359015/how-to-refer-to-excel-macros-not-functions-in-xlam-addin-saved-outside-person).