# How to refer to Excel macros (not functions) in .XLAM addin saved outside Personal Macro folder in Excel 2016/2019?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, add-in

We can create an .XLAM addin with custom functions (UDF). Once we connect Excel to the addin, these UDFs can then be called from another workbook regardless of where the addin was saved (even outside the Personal Macros folder).

But the same cannot be done for macros (sub-procedures) saved in the same .XLAM file. From my research and trial it seems the sub-procedures can be called correctly if the addin was saved in the Personal Macros folder. But if the addin was saved somewhere else, the macro would not show up in the Macro list upon pressing Alt-F8.

Is there a way around this? We need the addin to be saved in C:\OneDrive\Macros\Addin.xlam because the addin would update frequently so this saves the hassle when everybody updates it automatically via OneDrive.

We are using Excel 2016 and 2019.

Comment: Add-Ins are selected in `Developers -> Add-Ins` (or in settings). They can be turned off or on. You can point to any add-in file - no matter where it's located.

Comment: Create an update function in the macro instead. I have code for that at my office and can share it tomorrow. Meaning when you start Excel it will look for a new version of the xlam file, if there is a new version it will copy the new and replace the old in the users add-in folder.

Comment: Did you install the add-in?  Once you do that, and set a reference in the VBA UI, you should be able to do what you say.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how do I add a reference in VBA UI?

Comment: It is one of the menu options.  You should familiarize yourself with all of them.  For this one, Do an internet search for something like `VBA add a reference`, or `early-binding`.  These are concepts with which you should be familiar as a VBA programmer.

Comment: Thanks! I used the guide at https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calling-vba-in-add-ins-from-vba-modules to add references to my add-in. However the sub procedures in the add-in still do not show up in Alt-F8 view.

Comment: @Andreas could you share the code with me? jubinell at gmail dot com many thanks!

Comment: @Lun can't do it now for a few days but will post it later

Answer (score 5):

After several weeks of researching and trying out different methods, I found the best method as follows:

1. Make sure you saved your macro source (e.g. MyMacros.xlsm) as MyMacros.xlam so that the add-in contains the latest macros and functions.
2. Make sure MyMacros.xlam add-in is connected in Click File - Options (Or Alt - F, T) Add-Ins - Manage Excel Add-Ins - Go (G)
3. In the second Excel file (let's say MyExcel.xlsm), open VBA Editor (Alt-F11). Choose the MyMacros.xlam project and rename the name to MyMacros to be different (pic) In my example pics MyMacros is FreelensiaMacros.
4. If you have several XL files open, click on the MyExcel project in the left VBA Project List pane (not MyMacros!). Then go to Tools - References and select MyMacros from the list.
   You should now see a new reference in the VBA Project panel on the left side (pic)

[image]

5., Create a module named something like CallMyMacrosMod and type in several macro names from the MyMacros.xlam file using Application.Run such as:

```
   Sub FormatTables()
     Application.Run "MyMacros.FormatTables"
   End Sub
```

It is convenient to construct texts in the MyMacros.xlsm file itself storing the commands to call all of your macros. You can then copy and paste to Word (to avoid the [quotes problem](https://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes)), then copy from Word and paste in this VBA Editor.

[image]

6. Save and close the VBA window.
   You can now call the MyMacros macros from the macro list of MyExcel file without having to kep MyMacros open, simply by typing Alt-F8.

[image]

7. Save and close your XL file.

Sources:
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calling-vba-in-add-ins-from-vba-modules

Answer (score 1):

If the add-in is loaded, you can call any sub/function with the following code
Sub: `Application.Run "YourAddinSub",param1, param2, ...`
Function: `Application.Run("YourAddinFunction",param1, param2, ...)`

If needed, you can qualify the sub. For example: `YourAddin.YouAddinSub`