# How to use a macro from an addin excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

Im starting to program in excel VBA and what I want to do is:

1) When I open a new excel file (empty), I import the excel add-in

2) Then, I want to use the macro implemented on that add-in (in a module)

3) That add-in basically combines multiple excel worksheets (in the specified path), into a single one (the one where I ran the macro)
**Note: it works when not used as an add-in, that is, when used separately**

4) When i run the following code in an empty excel file, it doesn't put the other worksheets in there. It just opens the first excel file it finds, and nothing more happens.

Do you know what is the error I'm doing? Thanks in advice :) .

```
Sub GetSheets()

Path = "C:specified path\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet

    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `Path = "C:\specified path\"`?

Comment: Yes, I just changed my actual path  xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the code from an Addin, `ThisWorkbook` refers to the Addin-file, but I guess you want to merge everything in your first `ActiveWorkbook` as destination.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim destWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
    fPath = "C:\specified path\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fName <> ""
        Set currentWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath & fName, ReadOnly:=True)
        For i = 1 To currentWB.Sheets.Count
            currentWB.Sheets(i).Copy After:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)
        Next i
        currentWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        fName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

I suggest not use internal names like "Sheet" or "Filename" for your variables, so I changed their names.

If you always copy behind the first sheet, the sheet order is changed. So I changed it to append at the end instead.

As `Sheets` include chart sheets also, it is a better choice than `Worksheet` in this case. To loop over them, I suggest to use a counter, as ther is no `Sheet` object.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code above. It inserts the sheets ordered, which was something I didn't know how to do... But there's something i cannot understand. This code is supposed to be runned from the Addin right? I want to run the addin but not starting there; there is, I want to run the macro from my worksheet, but in this case I can't, because I don't have access to the addin macro right? I'm sorry for the silly questions.  -.-

Comment: Put the code into a module (not a worksheet's code), enable properties editor in VBA editor by F4, give that module an individual name e. g. "AddinCode", rename your first code line `Public Sub GetSheets()` and assign it to a button via `AddinCode.GetSheets` or start it manually from the list of macros. If you need a separate Addin menu with buttons, then search for "Custom UI Editor" as that is a longer story ... :)

Comment: Asger, I already did what you told me (change the name and make it public), but I don't want to have buttons to get the sheets... I want to run the macro, but this macro isn't on the list.

Comment: You can already assign it to the quick access toolbar. If you want to have it in the macro list, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53359015/10908769) may help (not sure). Marking answers is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).