# Create VSTO Workbook Library

Tags: excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I am currently running a .XLAM Add-In however, due to ease of deployment want to switch to a VSTO Add-In.
As the XLAM Add-In is basically a "hidden" Workbook, I put template sheets in there to import them when necessary.
The time to import is far faster compared to copying a template from another workbook somewhere else.

Is there a similar possibility to "store" sheets (or even mulitple workbooks) in a VSTO Add-In or is referencing other workbooks the only way?

Thank you already.

Comment: You'll have to reference another workbook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refer to Excel macros (not functions) in .XLAM addin saved outside Personal Macro folder in Excel 2016/2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359015/how-to-refer-to-excel-macros-not-functions-in-xlam-addin-saved-outside-person)